# Using variables from a class's constructor in one of its member functions?

Tags: c++, class, variables, constructor, scope

I'm learning C++ and I want to know if there is a way you can use variables defined in a class's constructor in a member function. I've tried looking online and in my textbook but I can't find a definitive answer. For example:

```
class Item {
public:
   Item(std::string str) {
      std::string text = str;
      int pos = -1;
   }
   void increment() {
      // how would I reference pos here?
      pos++;
   }
};
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `pos` and `text` should be data members of the whole class, hence accessible by all the member functions in the class (here, `increment()`).

Comment: Unless its a lambda, *no function* can access the local variables of another function. What you want is a data member of the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to know if there is a way you can use variables defined in a class's constructor in a member function.

No, you can't. Variables defined in the constructor goes out of scope at the end of the constructor.

The normal way is to initialize *member variables* in the constructor. These can then be accessed in the member functions:

```cpp
class Item {
public:
    Item(std::string str) : // colon starts the member initializer list
        text(std::move(str)),
        pos{-1} 
    {
        // empty constructor body
    }

    void increment() {
        pos++;         // now you can access `pos`
    }

private:
    // member variables
    std::string text;
    int pos;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to turn `text` and `pos` into private data members of the `Item` class.

*Private* because, if declared public, they could be easily overwritten making, for instance, redundant the `increment()` function, which is an undesirable side effect.

```
class Item {
public:
   Item(std::string str): text{str}, pos{-1} {}

   void increment() {
      pos++;
   }
   
   /* text and pos are now private data members, hence need 'get' functions
    in order to access their current value */
   std::string& getText() {
       return text;
   }

   int getPos() {
       return pos;
   }
private:
    // text and pos made private members
    std::string text;
    int pos;
};
```